# CSS3 transition issue

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am removing a bunch of div elements using jquery. What I want is when The div is removed then the rest of the div elements should animate to the top. My current code just removes it and the rest of the div elements shift immediately. How can I achieve this?

Below is my code

HTML

```
<div class="div"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>
<div class="div"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>
<div class="div"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>
<div class="div"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></div>
```

JS

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

CSS

```
.div {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YwWn5/)

Comment: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/YwWn5/1/) what you need?

Comment: yes but with css3 transition.

Comment: Ok, but remove won't work because it totally removes the element from DOM.

Comment: Thats what I want to remove DOM element completely.

Comment: I have updated  @26ph19's answer http://jsfiddle.net/YwWn5/2/ to remove div after it has finished sliding up

Comment: How can I do that with CSS3 transition?

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trik

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().slideUp("slow", function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/YwWn5/3/

Updated JS:

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    var $elem = $(this).parent();
    $elem.addClass('removing');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $elem.remove();
    }, 500);
});
```

Updated CSS:

```
.div {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: width 2s, height 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, margin 0.5s, padding 0.5s;
}
.removing {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I included margin and padding animation to prevent any jumps on element removal.  It's also important to note that I use a `setTimeout` to wait for the CSS animation to finish before actually removing the element.  If you're not concerned with the elements being removed from the DOM, and are okay with them remaining invisible on the page, you can remove that part altogether.

Comment: Sorry mate, it seems to be working fine. My mistake. I think there used to be this behavior in Firefox (atleast earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need CSS transition to do that, try :

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
   $(this).parent().hide(300, function(){
       $(this).remove();
   });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YwWn5/4/

Comment: This does not animate to the top in a sliding up motion. `hide` animates right to left and bottom to top as it hides.  The correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/24890782/682480 which *slides up*.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Who cares ? ^^ `hide()` is prettier and smoother I think

Comment: That's a matter of opinion, but along with that you answered 4 minutes after they did and all you did was change `slideUp` to `hide`. You could've added that as a comment to their answer IMO. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Actually, I didn't see the first answer because I was testing on JSFiddle and I didn't reload the page when posting. Note that the questionner only ask that the following divs should slide up, which is indeed what my function does. There is nothing about the way that the clicked div should disappear or explode or whatever.